# Is there a way to release a lock on table if a process that locked it is dead?

Tags: sql-server, database, locking

I'm interested if this is, anyhow, possible in SQL Server?

For some reason, I've expected RDBMS to be aware of the event, when the process that locked a table in its database, is dead in order to release the lock.

Comment: when a process is killed all the locks are released held by that process are you sure its not some other process thats holding locks on your rescources ??

Comment: @M.Ali sometimes after kill process hangs with rollback status till server restart...